# how to implement this sql in Laravel either using model or query builder?

Tags: sql, laravel

My sql code is :

```
SELECT b.item_id as breakfast,l.item_id as lunch, d.item_id as dinner
FROM breakfast_menus as b,lunch_menus as l,dinner_menus as d
where (b.day_id=3 and l.day_id=3 and d.day_id=3)
```

my models are:
breakfast_id model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class breakfast_item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'item'
    ];



}
```

breakfast_menu model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class breakfast_menu extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
        'day_id', 'item_id'
    ];

    public function item()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\breakfast_item', 'item_id');
    }
     public function day()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\day', 'day_id');
    }

}
```

day model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class day extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
        'day',
    ];

    public function breakfast_menu()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\breakfast_menu', 'day_id');
    }
}
```

and like this the rest models of lunch_items and lunch_menu,dinner_items and dinner_menu is declared. If required the models and relations can be changed. My main necessary is to show the data as a weekly view of breakfast ,lunch and dinner in a table

Comment: please share you models definitions & relations

Comment: thanks @OMR ,
plz check, I've updated the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your day Model, you have to define two relations:

```
public function lunch_menu()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\lunch_menu', 'day_id');
    }

public function dinner_menu()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\dinner_menu', 'day_id');
    }
```

then you load breakfast_menu,lunch_menu,dinner_menus for the day model where id for day =3

```
$value=day::find(3)->with(['breakfast_menu.item','lunch_menu.item',
'dinner_menus.item'])->get();
```

$value->breakfast_menu now is an object with an attribute called item witch has the 'id,item' field, you must check it out using debugger ....

for the literally converting you sql to ORM:

```
$values=Day:: addSelect([
'breakfast'=>breakfast_menu::select('breakfast_menus.item_id')
->where('breakfast_menus.item_id',3),
'lunch'=>lunch_menu::select('lunch_menus.item_id')
->where('lunch_menus.item_id',3),
'dinner'=>dinner_menu::select('dinner_menus.item_id')
->where('dinner_menus.item_id',3)
->get();
```

please note your original query doesn't get the items, but the item_id s